# Python3 tkinter lay invisible scrollbar over widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

I would like to lay an invisible scrollbar over a Treeview
I am using a raspberry pi and have a small touchscreen and I thus would like to use the space efficiently
I had to size up my scrollbar as I couldn't figure out how to make "swipe"-scrolling in a treeview possible
That's why I now have very little space and the font is almost too small
Is there any way to make a scrollbar invisible, but still usable when laying on another widget with eg. the place function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need scrollbars to scroll. All scrollable widgets have an api that is used for scrolling: the `xview` and `yview` methods. The scrollbar is just a convenient way to call those methods, but it's not the only way.

I don't know what events a swipe will send, but you can bind to those events and directly call the `xview` and/or `yview` methods yourself.

For example, let's assume for the moment that a touch is the `<B1>` event, and a swipe is the `<B1-Motion>` event. You can scroll with a swiping motion like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(...)
        self.tree.bind("<B1>", self.start_swipe)
        self.tree.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_swipe)
        ...

    def start_swipe(self, event):
        self.last_y = event.y

    def on_swipe(self, event):
        # only do the scrolling if the swipe is 10 pixels or more
        if abs(event.y - self.swipe_start) < 10:
            return

        # compute whether we are scrolling up or down
        delta = -1 if event.y > self.last_y else 1

        # remember this location for the next time this is called
        self.last_y = event.y

        # do the scroll
        self.tree.yview_scroll(delta, "units")
```

Comment: I also thought about that, but I can't find information about touch events anywhere :(

Comment: @marcoPolio: there's a real good chance that touch events are simply mapped to mouse buttons. Try the above code and see if it works.

Comment: darn you're right.. seems to work, thank you very much !!